# Merging dataframe rows that have a offset (generated the same day but bearing a different timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm trying to merge several dataframes, in each frame is data such as

```
timestamp   cap
0   1387118554000   3488670
1   1387243928000   1619159
2   1387336027000   2191987
3   1387435314000   4299421
4   1387539459000   9866232
```

Each value represents daily generated data, however each value was not generated at the exact same millisecond so the timestamps do not merge. I need a way to convert the timestamp into just the year, month and day components. Then I will be able to merge my data sets (unless there is another way to solve such an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
0   2013-12-15 14:42:34
1   2013-12-17 01:32:08
2   2013-12-18 03:07:07
3   2013-12-19 06:41:54
4   2013-12-20 11:37:39
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
print df
            timestamp      cap
0 2013-12-15 14:42:34  3488670
1 2013-12-17 01:32:08  1619159
2 2013-12-18 03:07:07  2191987
3 2013-12-19 06:41:54  4299421
4 2013-12-20 11:37:39  9866232
```

Then you can use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms').dt.date
print df
    timestamp      cap
0  2013-12-15  3488670
1  2013-12-17  1619159
2  2013-12-18  2191987
3  2013-12-19  4299421
4  2013-12-20  9866232
```

Or [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print df
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
       timestamp      cap  timestamp1
0  1387118554000  3488670  2013-12-15
1  1387243928000  1619159  2013-12-17
2  1387336027000  2191987  2013-12-18
3  1387435314000  4299421  2013-12-19
4  1387539459000  9866232  2013-12-20
```

Comment: Ah yes good idea, but we to return the daily timestamp so it's in the form '2013-12-15' then I will be able to merge

Comment: but we need to return* 

How can we convert in to just year year-month-day ?